# how to apply gradient color layer in dynamic table cell at reload in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I want to create gradient kind of color code and set into dynamic table view cell which height vary according to data.
I used layer when I am going to add into layer of table cell. I need exact table view cell height after table data load.

```
-(void)setTableData:(NSMutableArray *)tableData{

    tableHeightConstraints.constant  = cellHeight * tableData.count;

    _tableData = tableData;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [self greyGradient];
    bgLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);
    self.backgroundImageViewTc.image = [self greyImageFromGradient:bgLayer];

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}


+ (CAGradientLayer*) greyGradient {

    UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.85 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorThree     = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.7 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorFour = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.4 alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colors =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, colorThree.CGColor, colorFour.CGColor, nil];

    NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.02];
    NSNumber *stopThree     = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.99];
    NSNumber *stopFour = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: stopOne, stopTwo, stopThree, stopFour, nil];
    CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    headerLayer.colors = colors;
    headerLayer.locations = locations;

    return headerLayer;

}

+ (UIImage *) greyImageFromGradient:(CAGradientLayer*) layer{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.bounds.size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

this code can not able to create exact size image so it got blur.

Comment: Do you want to apply color to the cell or do you want to set height of cell ?

Comment: I want to apply gradient color to dynamic table cell. Question is how to create gradient color in such a way so i can set into dynamic table view cell's background.

Comment: Can you please show me some code that you did?

Comment: are you creating custom cell ? show some code or screen shot of what you want exactly.

Comment: now check source code That I have done yet.

Comment: @RaviMalviya Are you able to see the gradient color? Or you are facing problem of table view height?

Comment: yes i am able to see color but facing problem of table view height, that why created image got blur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here u  can find ur solution let me know if any issue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView )tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell )cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TVCell mycell = (TVCell )cell;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(mycell.cellBkView.frame.size.width, mycell.cellBkView.frame.size.height);

    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer greyGradient];
    bgLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    mycell.cellBkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[BackgroundLayer greyImageFromGradient:bgLayer]];
}
```

Comment: Ok I got it willDisplayCell method will give me exact dynamic cell height thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: where I put this code after reload? and how i get indexPath is it from [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]

Comment: Yes Where you want the Height.

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is not available